# CORS Error (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) while connecting websockets (Sockjs, stomp-websocket)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm try to open sockets in my React App. I am using Java (Spring ) for back-end and React for front-end.

in **ComponentDidMount** I added the Following code, which I copied from Spring Documentation.

```
    componentDidMount () {

    let socket = new SockJS('http://172.16.10.154:8099/ws');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/notify/1152923083608410997', function (greeting) {
            console.log("Geeting is ",greeting)
        });
    });
}
```

now when **ComponentDidMount** is call, I get the following error in console
[image: Console Error]

I tried the exact same code in a static html file, where I put this code in  and call this on a button Click. The strange thing is that it's working in that file.
What could be the possible reason for this problem? Is it from back-end?

Comment: 99% of the time CORS is a backend issue.

Comment: How did you resolve it ?